# What are these historic tools?

Tags: identification, everyday-objects

I ask this question under to on topic heading of 'cultures and historical practices.'

Can anyone identify these two objects?

I thought the silver rod was either some kind of sewing or medical instrument and the wooden one some kind of carpentry jig. But I cannot confirm either of them one way or the other.

Both were flea market finds, but the sellers did not know what they were.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are the measurements of both items?

Comment: @SteveBird, let me double check and then update my post.

Comment: @SteveBird, sorry for the slow turnaround, they are both about 1 foot long.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The bottom one is a [moulding plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moulding_plane) which is very similar to [this example](https://www.oldtoolmart.co.uk/onlineshop/prod_7224917-Moulding-Plane-Turner.html).

> Traditionally, moulding planes were blocks of wear resistant hardwood, often beech or maple, which were worked to the shape of the intended moulding. The blade, or iron was likewise formed to the intended moulding profile and secured in the body of the plane with a wooden wedge.

Your example appears to be missing the blade.

I'm less sure about the other one (since there's nothing to give scale) but it looks a lot like a [Curette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curette) such as [this one](https://bossinstruments.com/product/11-thomas-uterine-curette-blunt-mall-4/).

> A curette is a surgical instrument designed for scraping or debriding biological tissue or debris in a biopsy, excision, or cleaning procedure. In form, the curette is a small hand tool, often similar in shape to a stylus; at the tip of the curette is a small scoop, hook, or gouge.

Comment: I am pretty sure you are right about the Curette. If you look above the handle, there is a "2" engraved. Now compare it with this [#2 variant](https://bossinstruments.com/product/11-thomas-uterine-curette-blunt-mall-2/), and the proportions very much match. Also, the ceramic tile background would also give a size hint. I would expect that to indicate around 10-15cm/4-6 inches per tile.

Comment: Wow, great matches! Now, while the moulding plane is an old item, replaced in modern times with spinning router bits, the curette is apparently still used in modern medicine. Although the item in my picture may be old. Not sure if that is of historic interest.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis Wow, I worked with moulding plane similar to yours yesterday. It feels quite strange to see someone asking on History about a thing I consider everyday tool. And I  am not even THAT old :D. By the way your moulding plane is not regular one, note that it has shaped body, this leads me to presume it is specialized for shaping some specific profile rather than general smoothing.

Comment: @byMaelstromer I like wood working with manual tools tool, but in modern times cutting moulding with router bits seems way more common.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis ... and much more convenient, since router  can by used instead of multitude of 'unpowered' tool. I just prefer to do thing in the hard way, since can't seems to stand the noise.